# How to achieve recursive join in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I have three tables A, B and C. B has a fix balance, while A has amount which required to update with fix balance and push these combine records into C.
ex.-
B has 100rs balance, A has three records 50,-10,-40.
I am using a mview which does A LEFT JOIN B and updating records in C.

output required in C:
150,140,100

output comes in C:
150,90,60

since its a join its taking balance for all three records as 100 and that's the reason I am getting 150,90,60. But I want 150,140,100.

Is there any way to do it in clickhouse ?

schemas for A, B and C are

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;
CREATE TABLE A
(
id UInt64,
`date` DateTime,
user_id UInt64,
status LowCardinality(String),
amount Float64,
sign Int8
) ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree(sign) order by (user_id, id);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS C;
create table C
(
 user_id UInt64,
 id UInt64,
 closing_balance Float64,
 amount Float64,
 status LowCardinality(String),
 `date` DateTime,
 sign Int8
) ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree(sign) PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(date) 
order by (user_id, id);



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B;
create table B
(
 user_id UInt64,
 id UInt64,
 closing_balance Float64,
 amount Float64,
 status LowCardinality(String),
 `date` DateTime,
 sign Int8
) ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree(sign) order by (user_id);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B_mview;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW B_mview to B
as SELECT * from C order by id asc;
```

insertion query is :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A_mview;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW A_mview TO C AS SELECT A.company_id AS 
company_id,
    A.user_id AS user_id,
    A.id AS id,
    round((multiIf(A.status != 'Complete',
B.closing_balance,plus(A.amount,B.closing_balance))),2) AS 
closing_balance,
    A.amount AS amount,
    A.date AS date,
    toInt8(1) AS sign
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.user_id=B.user_id
```

Comment: could you provide the table's schemas and insert-commands for test data?

Comment: if not a closed session requirement use temporary tables.

Comment: @vladimir I have updated the question with schemas and insert commands, please have a look at it.

Comment: @PrakharNigam I can't confirm how many records are going to come in A, so how many temporary tables i have to go for, can you please explain more?